# How to remove square drawn around window resize handle in an NSScrollview?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I have an NSScrollview that takes up an entire window. The scrollview has a vertical scrollbar  but no horizontal scrollbar. The window color is gray. The window is resizable.

Cocoa automatically draws a white square with a light gray border around the window's resize handle (right below the bottom of the vertical scroller). I would like to remove that little white square so that the gray window color and resize grooves show through. How do I do that?

[Share photos on twitter with Twitpic http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/27dcp1.png](http://twitpic.com/27dcp1)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try setting the scroll view's background color to `[NSColor clearColor]`.

Comment: Proven advice instead of wild guesses would be much more helpful. I am having the same problem and your hint didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Send the window a setShowsResizeIndicator:NO and draw your own indicator as you like...

Comment: I tried this. The problem with this is then the scrollbar travels all the way to the bottom of the window, leaving no room for a resize indicator to be custom drawn.